# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Substring.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') - swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am working on a little project. to avoid nil value, I am using if condition

```
if let _result = _fullString.suffix(from: startIndex!){
//do something 
}
```

but it shows error

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'Substring.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')

Comment: Please, this is Swift: No *objective-c-ish* variables with leading underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Is happens because suffix function not returning any optional value. that's why it cause optional binding is failed.

You can directly use suffix value by using below code

```
let _result = _fullString.suffix(from: startIndex!)
```

Comment: but sometimes suffix function return nil, how to avoid nil?

Comment: @BestoftheBest String class only return non-optional suffix value. So no need of optional binding.